# How to fix double click problem in this code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

https://media.giphy.com/media/WrOMxTqq1IxmytsvPQ/giphy.gif

Please see the gif above to better understand what's going on. On first click they all work normally but after first click I have to double click them to select them. I'm not a advanced developer so I've been trying to figure this out for straight 2 hours and last choice I wanted to ask you guys.

I declared select effect here. (White circle) And added an Array to get all select effects.

```
    public GameObject selectEffect;
    private bool isSelected = false;
    public GameObject[] selectEffectArray;
```

I put them inside the Array.

```
    private void Awake()
    {
        selectEffectArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("planetSelected");
        selectEffect = transform.Find("selectEffect").gameObject;
    }
```

I deactivate all select effects on start.

```
    void Start()
    {
        Deactivate();
    }
```

Here's Deactivate code.

```
    void Deactivate()
    {
        foreach (GameObject effect in selectEffectArray)
        {
            effect.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

When I click one of the planets these happens. (I'm a little confused so I hope you can understand it.)

```
    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        if (isSelected)
        {
            selectEffect.SetActive(false);
            travelbutton.SetActive(false);
            isSelected = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Deactivate();

            planetName_text.text = planet.name;
            requiredFuel_text.text = planet.requiredFuel.ToString();
            travelbutton.SetActive(true);
            selectEffect.SetActive(true);
            isSelected = true;
        }

    }
```

I don't want to double click a planet to select it.

Comment: The first time OnMouseUp() is hit you enter the 'else' condition, and everything works as expected. However, the second time the if(isSelected) condition is hit, which removes the effect from the last selected button but doesn't apply the effect to the new selected item. Then when you enter OnMouseUp the third time, you again enter the 'else' condition which effects the new item. Can you remove everything in OnMouseUp but the logic within the 'else' condition and get the results you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void OnMouseUp()
{
    if (isSelected)
    {
        // selectEffect.SetActive(false);  // no longer needed as the Deactivate() method will clear all effects
        travelbutton.SetActive(false);
        isSelected = false;
    }       

    // removed else as we always want to effect the selected item
    Deactivate();

    planetName_text.text = planet.name;
    requiredFuel_text.text = planet.requiredFuel.ToString();
    travelbutton.SetActive(true);
    selectEffect.SetActive(true);
    isSelected = true;        

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It always helps to draw a state machine when working through these sorts of logic puzzles. The top drawing is how you want your code to work (iS = isSelected, OMU = onMouseUp). The bottom is how it actually works. As others have said, the problem arises when calls to Deactivate turn the effect off but don't change isSelected, leading to an additional click necessary to make isSelected false before the effect can be properly triggered.

[image: State Machine]